# Why proofs which provide algorithms for construction are valid?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

10 days ago I asked question about validity of a proof ([Is this a valid proof of the fact that a subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space has a basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032843/is-this-a-valid-proof-of-the-fact-that-a-subspace-of-an-n-dimensional-vector-s)), but as I later realised I didn't explain well what I really wanted to know and this resulted in the answers that didn′t quite answered my real question, so I will try to rephrase it. So in that previous post there was a proof of the fact that any subspace of finite-dimensional vector space has a finite basis. In it I basically constructed this basis by adding vector if the current set of vectors is not maximal linear independent set. Then I said that this "algorithm" will terminate because of the fact that the vector space is finite dimensional. But my concern about this proof is "Why algorithm for constructing/finding an object is a valid proof of its existence ?". Such question may sound strange, but my concern is the fact that you can′t say by reading a proof how many steps execution of such algorithm will take, because it depends on what vector space and what subspace you take. So basically we don't know how many steps the proof has and it seems kind of strange to me. And this concern is not just about proof of this fact about subspaces, but about any proof which proves existence of an object with an algorithm which has number of steps which depends on something. For example, proof of the fact that any tree has a vertice of degree 1, where you take any vertice and then go along the edges of the tree until you find the vertice of degree 1 (which you will, because tree has only finite amount of vertices and tree is acyclic).

So why are proofs, which provide algorithms for constructing an object, valid and can we formalise (maybe using set theory) them in such a way that number of steps of a proof will be specific ?

Comment: Reasonable people can disagree, whether on the basis of intuition or on the basis of formalism, about what counts as a 'valid' construction or algorithm. There are gradations of this concept. Most people would not have difficulty with the argument given in the post you link. Most people would regard an algorithm for constructing something as a valid proof of that thing's existence, unless they dismiss the process as not an 'algorithm' or have qualms about how complex an algorithm can get before it is inadmissible. It may help to give more examples of forms of inference that you question.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursive definitions and how they are formalized?  That's basically all you're doing, is defining what happens in the "$n$th step of the algorithm" by recursion on $n$.

Comment: @EricWofsey You mean that we can recursively define function from natural numbers to finite inearly independent subsets of vector subspace, which will reflect the steps of the algorithm ?

Comment: Sure, for that particular proof.

Comment: @EricWofsey Then I have a follow-up question. When we recursively define some function f, we need to define a function h using which we will define f(n+1)=h(f(n)). But now it seems to me that in order to define a function h in the case of this proof I will need to use axiom of choice, because for every linearly independent subset of vector subspace I need to choose a vector from the difference of subspace and span of this subset, so it seems to me that I will need to make a choice from each of infinite number of sets. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, for the most obvious way to formulate the proof using recursion, it requires the axiom of choice to fix a choice function at the start.  It's possible to avoid the axiom of choice by more clever formulations (for instance, you can prove by induction on $n$ that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, either there is a basis or there is a linearly independent set of $n$ elements).

Comment: More broadly, whenever you see any sort of "iterative process" in any mathematical argument, that is pretty much always an informal way of saying some sort of argument using induction, though the exact way to formalize it using induction may not always be totally obvious.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you, you've pretty much answered my question fully in the comments. Maybe you could post it as an answer so that I could accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sort of "iterative process" is really just an informal way of describing a proof by induction.  For instance, in this case, you could formulate your argument as a proof by induction on $j$ that for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$ either $M$ has a basis or there exists a linearly independent subset of $M$ of size $j$.  The induction step of this argument is just exactly what you do in step $j$ of your argument: either your linearly independent subset of size $j$ (which you have by the induction hypothesis) is already a basis, or else you can enlarge it to a linearly independent subset of size $j+1$.  The idea that the algorithm must eventually stop can then be described as the statement that when you take $j=n+1$, it is not possible to have a linearly independent subset of size $j$, so there must exist a basis for $M$.

Or, you could more directly mimic your proof by defining your basis recursively (though this of course is ultimately again a proof by induction, since that's how you prove that recursive definitions make sense, and the most naive formulation of the recursive definition would also use the axiom of choice).  Namely, you recursively define a sequence of sets $(A_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, where your "step $j$" just tells you how to define $A_{j+1}$ from $A_j$.  Note that in the case that $A_j$ is already a basis, you can simply define $A_{j+1}=A_j$, so that you don't have to worry about not knowing how long the recursion will be.

Answer (score 0):

The proof implictly (or explicitly) relies on the fact that there is a *progress function*, i.e. some quantity that is guaranteed to decrease on every iteration and has a lower bound. Such as the dimension of the "unspanned space", which is obviously a non-negative number. That guarantees that the iterations will terminate.

This situation could be compared to a proof by induction, where you make steps that depend on each other and could be seen as an algorithm (the progress function would be the number of inductive steps remaining before you reach the target $n$). Or even a non-terminating algorithm.

If you still don't like this vision, think that you can always "unroll" the loop and write a standard, though possibly very long proof for any dimension.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases where such questions arise, you will prove things like $\forall x \in M: P(x)$, i. e., you have to prove by definition of $\forall$ for every single object $x \in M$ that the statement $P(x)$ holds.
An algorithm shows, given a particular $x$, the validity of $P(x)$ using finitely many steps.

Please note that the "finitely many steps" is essential in proofs. In mathematical logic, we define that we can "deduce" a statement $S$ from an axiom system $Ax$, if we can get $S$  from $Ax$ by applying finitely often inference rules (things line $A \land B \implies A$).

Otherwise, we could prove that $1 + 1 + 1 + \dots$ converges using that $0 + 0 + 0 + \dots$ converges and changing infinitely often a Zero to a One.

Comment: But as far as I know in that case (when we want to prove some statement with "for all" quantifier) we need the proof to be "uniform" over x in a sense that the proof must not depend on any "properties of x" except the fact that x is from M. But I can't really write out the full list of logical steps of such proof in case of the statement mentioned in the post beacuse I don't know the length of the list, I only know that the list "will terminate" if we take some specific dimension.

Comment: _Given a specific subspace / vector space_, you know that you could write out such a list. Despite the algorithm seems rather "constructivistic" at a first sight, it is non-constructivistic: Depending on which linear independent element you choose to add next, the list could be arbitrary long -- but finite (note that you will show later that finite-dimensional vector spaces have same basis sizes.

Comment: Formally, a little bit hidden in the proof is a "proof by induction". (The remaining vector space becomes smaller and smaller, down to dimension 0). The idea is that you have proven already the statement for the smaller (lower-dimensional) rest and you show how we can use the result to prove this for higher-dimensional spaces by reusing the already proven statement for smaller vector spaces.